# What would be the best way to turn the seeker into the Arcane Archer?

Tags: dnd-4e, house-rules, class-feature, class

So, this is supposed to be simple.

I wanted to turn the Seeker into the Arcane Archer class since the Arcane Archer is something that most people in my group wanted to play as and there's no REAL way to do so according to the RAW anyways.

I wanted to make it an INT class and change some of the features that seem "too primal" to make it feel arcane but my biggest concern is with the numbers.

In other words:

Balancewise, how could I change the seeker to make it feel like an INT based arcane class and still maintain balance?

Comment: Can you be more specific on why a simple refluff is not enough? Eg, I had a player with a big muscular avenger, and his str/con stats were low to average. As long as the numbers are right, the system don't care about how you describe stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Refluff the attacks into something appropriately arcane.

The seeker's *capabilities* are fine, it's just the descriptions which are problematic. For this instance, either swap the primary stat to int (it doesn't harm anything) and just describe the attacks as energy and arcane based, or ... simply describe the capabilities appropriately.

Comment: If it was merely about fluff, but it isn't.
If the seeker becomes an Int Dex class, it's already very different than the WIS DEX seeker already.

Int and Dex are good for your AC, but they both will be used for your Reflex defense. If the seeker has INT as its primary ability, his AC is likely to be higher than the WIS seeker but he will lack a good Will defense.

The question is simple, the answer requires a lot of thinking with the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

My best answer I'd say is either pick an arcane class that you like that uses Int for attacks and roll it as an Archer. You can acquire a ki focus through multiclassing or by taking certain themes. Using a ki focus will allow you to wield a non enchanted bow and use the power of the implement through the bow. Usually says "magic ki focused bow", for example, on power cards.

Also, there's the artificer. A class that utilizes crossbows as both a weapon and implement and uses Int as it's primary stat along with Wis or Con as secondary. This is probably the closest thing to an Arcane Archer that I can think of that doesn't require heavy refluffing. And since it allows you to use a crossbow as both an implement AND weapon you would not need to acquire a ki focus and could simply enchant the crossbow itself.

Artificers are covered in Eberron Player's Guide.

Ki focus can be obtained through the monk or assassin classes or the elemental initiate theme published in Heroes of Elemental Chaos.